# Answer with a link to deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

This answer :
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/13976/20065
points to this question :
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13282/freelance-programming-sites/13565#13565

Since I can not see deleted question, what should happen to this answer?

Also, I do want to see the deleted question. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deleted question is actually closed as a duplicate to [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51591/sites-for-getting-freelancer-jobs), which contains a more complete list of freelance sites.

Best solution in this case would be to probably edit the existing answer to point to this non-deleted post instead of the deleted post, although in other cases where there isn't a good non-deleted duplicate, we'd probably want to edit the answer to remove the dead link (or remove the answer itself it the only content it contained was the dead link).

In the rare event that the deleted post contains valuable information that is linked to from many places, it may qualify to be undeleted and a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/158605) placed on it. That type of action usually depends on the content, how many views/votes the post has, and how many links go to it, and the deleted post you mention probably would not qualify because of it's low number of views (770).

Also to answer your question about what you can do to see a deleted post when you don't have 10K+ reputation, you can try to find the post on [the Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) or [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), or you could try asking in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) or perhaps even here on [Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) to see if a user with 10K+ rep or a moderator would be nice enough to get you a copy of the post.

Answer (score 3):

This is why we discourage link-only answers. Once a link dies, the answer pretty much becomes worthless. In this case the answer still has some worth since the answer is only pointing to additional resources, that in this case couldn't be easily summarized.

The question of what should happen to this answer is a bit of a moot point since the question was just closed. However taken as an example, if a question doesn't stand up on it's own without the link, you should let the answerer know that link-only answers are generally not acceptable and flag it for moderator attention.